# Setting the value of Date Filter in ExtJS Grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to set the value of date filter of `ExtJS` grid as follows.

```
var tempDt={on:new Date("10/14/2015")};
filter.setValue(tempDt);
```

But on `line 2` the browser gets unresponsive.
This problem is occurring specially in `Mozilla Firefox`. `Chrome` doesn't produce this problem.

Please help me on this.

Comment: May be some problem with the format. Try to change the date format to the filter dateFormat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. According to the @Gilsha's comment. I have changed the line,

`var tempDt={on:new Date("10/14/2015")};`

to

`var tempDt={on:Ext.Date.parse("10/14/2015", "m/d/Y")};`

So, that was the problem of parsing.